# Did work, now it doesn't, oauth 2.0 no user data

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Here's my dilemma in a nutshell. Working on Google OAuth2, setting up Sign in with Google, I didn't use `access_type='offline'` before. Now I do, set up to store refresh variable in a table, and the refresh worked, for a moment. Now I can not sign in. This is my first real venture into using OAuth2, let alone specifically with Google. I've tried debugging and tracing, but /var/www/apache2/error.log says nothing except that the `$user` is not set.

Sadly, I'm the only one working on this project. I can't bounce my code off of a coworker, as I'm the only developer. Hence, if it's something blatantly obvious (misplaced `;` or `,`) that's why. Please, where did I mess up?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b7seb5v1nivh3df/files.zip

https://www.dropbox.com/s/eixxz71nm11u8jq/google.php

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbdj6z3a8coczfc/oauth2callback.php

**EDIT:**
Forgot to mention. My code that shows what I did is in the above link. Zip file contains the two php files. Whichever you prefer, the zip or the two `php` files, if you rather security. Dropbox does not parse the code if you click the link, no exe or anything. I just am at my wit's end.

Comment: Could you post some HTTP traces, so we can see what’s going back and forth between your program and Google?  It’s hard to guess what might be going on without that.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to do that. What I do know is that it goes as far as setting the session variables, so it does hit line 60 in google.php, but it appears that the `$gClient->getAccessToken()` on 54 of same never gets activated.

Comment: How can I get those traces for you? I am willing to get them, just no idea how to.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to leave this up in case anyone comes up with something. As for me, since everything is becoming more and more time sensitive, I'm going to scrap using the Google-provided php library, and go with a 3rd party OAuth script route.

Comment: My 2c, is don't use a third party oauth library. It's so easy to construct the URLs yourself, and then if something goes wrong, you can find and fix the problem straight away. Ultimately, it is only *two* urls. The first is sent as a redirect to the browser which eventually results in your defined callbackUrl being called. Then there is a second url to convert the returned (or stored) refresh token into an access token. You could learn how to do this in less time than it will take you to research and implement a third party library.

Comment: pinoyyid is right.  Have a look at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login